# User defined (or emmited) username when using the logger(1) linux bash tool command

Tags: bash, logging, syslog

I am trying to log some custom logs. The problem is that if I use the logger command, the username running the command is also logged. I would like to ommit that info so I can manually fill anything I want. I have read the manual but could not find anything like that. I also tried implementing it in a script (java) but not quit succeed.

Example. Now I am seeing this:

```
Mar  2 10:31:28 $HOSTNAME $USERNAME: Hello world!
```

What I would like to see is this:

```
Mar  2 10:31:28 suhosin[666]: ALERT - canary mismatch on efree() - heap overflow detected (attacker '000.000.000.000', file 'xyz')
```

Comment: @DmitriChubarov I edited my original post as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-t` option to set the tag.

```
$ logger -t 'nobody' 'hello'
```

Produces log:

```
Feb 28 10:25:37 myhostname nobody: hello
```

Relevant man page section (bold added for emphasis):

> -t, --tag tag
>
> Mark every line to be logged with the specified tag. **The default             tag is the name of the user logged in on the terminal** (or a user name based on effective user ID).

Comment: Is there an option to also change the hostname? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have indeed. The only thing mentioned is with the rfc5424 option to emit the hostname command. Though I am not sure that I want to change the rfc and also they is no mention as to which rfc is the default one (standard).